# How to check if an attribute is a Boolean attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to check if some HTML attribute are Boolean? for example:

```
<input type="text" name="input" disabled=""/>
```

Here the `disabled` attribute is Boolean, I have some code and I need check before setting value whether that attribute is Boolean or not.

Why I need this?

As mentioned [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) we can have either `""` or property name itself as the valid value not `true` or `false`.

Comment: May I ask _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: Every attribute is defined as standard. Data-tags can be checked with 'is data-tag === "true"' ...

Comment: As @Nunien correctly told you in his now deleted answer, you can check for your element's property equivalent. `typeof yourInput.disabled === 'boolean'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's basically no distinction on the level of HTML. If the attribute is simply the name without value, e.g. `<input disabled>`, that's a sure sign that it's a boolean attribute. However, if it's using the `name="value"` notation, then there's no way to distinguish it. Is `class="class"` a boolean attribute? No, it's a `classList` with one entry `"class"`. How about `foo=""`? Well, it's either a boolean attribute opting for the empty-value notation, or it's an attribute with no value set.

Only the interpreter assigns boolean-ness to an attribute; i.e. while parsing the HTML into a DOM, the interpreter sets DOM attributes like this, roughly speaking:

```
domElement.disabled = htmlElement.hasAttribute('disabled');
```

If you want to know what HTML elements are booleans, you need to do the same thing an interpreter does: keep a list of DOM elements whose attributes have types and interpret the HTML according to that specification.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you have the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operand in the following way:

```
var check_input = document.getElementById("check-input");

if(typeof(check_input.disabled) === "boolean"){
  alert('Yes');
}
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9t6eq5q2/) with the complete code. I hope that my answer can help you!